# How can I ensure my aggregation filters out subdocuments that are past expiry date in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to count the number of resetPassword (subdocument in Users schema) codes that are currently active. For a code to be active it's expiry date must be **greater than** the current date.

Here is my users schema. If someone requests to reset there password, we'll push a new `{ code: X, expiresAt, createdAt }` Object to the array.

```
id: { type: String, unique: true },
resetPassword: [
  {
    code: String,
    expiresAt: Date,
    createdAt: Date,
  },
],
```

I'm having an issue trying to $sum the total number of active reset codes. Here is the query I'm running that returns an empty array...note that if I were to remove the `resetPassword.expiresAt: { $gt: nowDateInMilliseconds() }` match section, it will return all the codes. I've tried moving this match statement out of the intial `$match` stage then doing an unwind & a match on the expiresAt but this didn't work either.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "id": userId,
      'resetPassword.expiresAt': {
        $gt: nowDateInMillisec(),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$id',
      totalValidResetCodes: {
        $sum: {
          $size: '$resetPassword',
        },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

This returns an empty array, even though I've got the expiry dates set to a date in the future.

I also tried the following with the same result (notice how I added $unwind and another $match to the pipeline)

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "id": userId,
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$resetPassword',
  },
  {
    $match: {
      'resetPassword.expiresAt': {
        $gt: nowDateInMillisec(),
      },
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$id',
      totalValidResetCodes: {
        $sum: {
          $size: '$resetPassword',
        },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

- `nowDateInMillisec()` - This simply returns the current date in milliseconds from epoch.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps a type mismatch.  Does it behave differently if you use date type instead milliseconds?

Comment: @Joe You beauty! That was it...I thought it was okay to use the `milliseconds` and that Mongo would handle the conversion there! If you want to add your answer in I'll accept it.

Comment: @Joe Am I right in inserting dates as `milliseconds` when I have setup a `Date` type in my mongoose schema? Instead of using the `Date` type, should I use an `Integer` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joe answered my question in the comments. He hinted that using a milliseconds since epoch time in the match filter wouldn't work since I'm using a `Date` type in my Mongoose schema.

So instead of doing this: `$gt: nowDateInMillisec(),` I simply used a `Date` type like so: `$gt: new Date(),`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$reduce` in `$project`, instead of your all process, you need to return ISOdate from this `nowDateInMillisec()`,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { id: 1 } },
  {
    $project: {
      totalValidResetCodes: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$resetPassword",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $gt: ["$$this.expiresAt", nowDateInMillisec()] },
                  // If you really want to pass timestamp then try below line
                  // { $gt: ["$$this.expiresAt", { $toDate: nowDateInMillisec() }] },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6zpAFwSFVPr)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my research, date format when stored in mongodb format should work for milliseconds as well. The below test is for up to a minute.

```
> db.users13.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e03768379a4e3f957641d"),
        "id" : "johnc",
        "resetPassword" : [
                {
                        "code" : "abc",
                        "expiresAt" : ISODate("2020-09-02T09:11:18.394Z"),
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:11:18.394Z")
                },
                {
                        "code" : "mno",
                        "expiresAt" : ISODate("2020-08-25T09:26:18.394Z"),
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-25T08:11:18.394Z")
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e06938379a4e3f957641f"),
        "id" : "katey",
        "resetPassword" : [
                {
                        "code" : "j2c",
                        "expiresAt" : ISODate("2020-09-02T08:48:18.394Z"),
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:11:18.394Z")
                },
                {
                        "code" : "rml",
                        "expiresAt" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:26:18.394Z"),
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:11:18.394Z")
                }
        ]
}
> db.users13.aggregate([ 
   {$unwind:"$resetPassword"}, 
   {$match:{"resetPassword.expiresAt":{$gt:ISODate()}}} 
 ]).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e03768379a4e3f957641d"),
        "id" : "johnc",
        "resetPassword" : {
                "code" : "abc",
                "expiresAt" : ISODate("2020-09-02T09:11:18.394Z"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:11:18.394Z")
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e06938379a4e3f957641f"),
        "id" : "katey",
        "resetPassword" : {
                "code" : "j2c",
                "expiresAt" : ISODate("2020-09-02T08:48:18.394Z"),
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-01T08:11:18.394Z")
        }
}
> ISODate()
ISODate("2020-09-01T08:31:37.059Z")
>
```